# ASUS RT-AC68U port forwarding fails intermittently

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

I have HTTP, HTTPS and app servers that are accessible by port forwarding for SME (on a budget).

However, it seems that the port forwarding fails intermittently. It shows "the page is taking too long to load" or just keeps trying to load for quite a long time before loading finally.

I have factory reset (and reconfigured) the router. It still fails, significantly lesser, but still quite often.

I'm pretty much out of options. Any recommendations for a reliable router? Instead of thinking about gazillions of users, lets go with reliability of basic functions and router that's not full of security holes first.

Of course, if you experienced something like that before and want to suggest something to check/uncheck/configure to save the SME some money, you're more than welcome to do so.

Comment: Have you tried rMerlin or DD-WRT firmware, this device is more than robust enough to handle significant port forwarding and high traffic volumes, but your Storage Made Easy solution (I am guessing that's what you meant by SME since you didn't really clarify) may be to much for most consumer grade routers, even high-end ones. But how much traffic are talking about here? The router should be able to handle 200-300Mbs full duplex on a wired interface with 40 or maybe even 50+ active sessions with no issues, assuming your server can handle that.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear. I'm using "SME" for "Small Medium Enterprise" to highlight the budget constraints. The only one doing anything with the router is me, 0 users, 0kbps in 0kbps out when I hit the problem while accessing it. I'm using the latest firmware 3.0.0.4.380_4164-gcc3b748. The servers perform perfectly when pointing to localhost, So I'm just going to assume that it's ASUS's fault, especially since restoring hardware default made things slightly better even if it's for a little while. I will try DD-WRT.

Comment: I would suggest rMerlin firmware... https://asuswrt.lostrealm.ca/ It's easy to use, supports stuff like the Asus apps too.